# Where is the leaks here?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"type"])
    {
        items       = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        currentname = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentid   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
```

how can resolv leaks problem

Comment: Tried running XCode's static analyzer? What's the symptoms? Tried using instruments?

Comment: you will probably need to provide a bit more context ti receive meaningful answers. Are these iVar in class or are these local variables to a method/function? What do you do afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

```
currentElement = [elementName copy];
items          = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
currentname    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
currentid      = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

You leak previous value stored in these ivars.

Comment: yes I do All Clips of new values ​​for I read from an xml data file that why I crushed the old valeus

Comment: @B.Moahmmed.Amine For the old values, you cannot just let go... You are responsible to release them since you created them.

Answer (score 1):

- `currentElement = [elementName copy];`
- `items = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`
- `currentname = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];`
- `currentid = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];`

These all cause memory leak if the method `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` runs more than once.

An easy way to fix this issue is to change your variables to properties. For example, in your header file, change:

```
@interface SomeClass {
    NSMutableDictionary *items;
}
```

to:

```
@interface SomeClass {
}

@property (retain) NSMutableDictionary *items;
```

And add this after `@implementation SomeClass`:

```
@synthesize items;
```

Then change your original code to:

```
self.items = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Both "Analyze" feature in Xcode and Instruments are your friend when you want to check memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that there is a leak in this snippet, I assume you already ran Instruments, which told you that the NSString object "elementName" was leaking.

Romain is right: a good step is to run the Xcode Static Analyzer. It will probably tell you that `[elementName copy]` returns an object with a retain count of +1. (Per Cocoa conventions, all "copy" selectors transfer the ownership of the returned object to your code).

So the solution here is to balance the "copy" call by releasing the copied object when you don't need it, using:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{ 
     [currentElement release];
     currentElement = [elementName copy];

     // your method body here…
 }
```

Comment: i have write [currentElement release]; but same problem. i think my problem here



-(void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL{
 donnes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
 xmlparser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
 [xmlparser setDelegate:self];
 [xmlparser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
 [xmlparser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
 [xmlparser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
 [xmlparser parse];
 

}